# Can't print to network printer from Windows shell

Tags: windows-xp, printing, network-printer

I have a networked printer (HP DeskJet 712C) that is shared via a Windows XP host.  I'm able to print to the printer from applications such as Word, gVim, and Notepad, but when I try and print to it directly via `print /D:"\\hostname\HP DeskJet 712C" file.txt` the shell will respond `the file file.txt is currently being printed`, but nothing will go to the printer.

I should add that while I've primarily been doing the printing from Windows 7 hosts, it happens on both Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit) and Windows XP hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the DJ712C is a host-based printer. It relies on the operating system and driver to convert the page into dots on the paper. It does not understand plain text. That is why it works fine when you are using the driver to print, not if you're sending text to it.

One way to get around the problem is to use [DOSPRN](http://www.dosprn.com/). It takes the text from DOS applications and passes it through the driver so the printer can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you are issuing the command.  Is it from within a command (DOS) window?

If so, try entering this command in your command window:

NET USE LPT1:\servername\printername

On my system, the command is retained from one session to others, but you may need to add the PERSISTENT=YES tag to it.

For more details, use NET USE /? in the command window.

Comment: Given that this was nearly 11 years ago, I don't exactly recall. :) I would imagine it was from a command window, though.